# How do I display a UIAlertView at the time I call it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

So, similar to this question:

[UIAlertView taking time to show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685534/uialertview-taking-time-to-show)

I'm running into a problem where my UIAlertView is not displaying until after all of my other code has run.

I have tried using the

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    [self presentLoadingAlertWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Creating Account...", nil)];

});
```

But I was unable to get it to change what happens. Currently, a user clicks a button and it triggers createAccountButtonReleased. Then it seems to skip over the dispatch_async part, run the rest of the code, and then come back to it.

```
- (IBAction)createAccountButtonReleased:(id)sender {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    [self presentLoadingAlertWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Creating Account...", nil)];

});

if ((![self.firstNameTextField hasText] && ![self.lastNameTextField hasText]) || ![self.emailTextField hasText] || ![self.passwordTextField hasText]) {
    [self dismissAlert:^(void){  [self presentOkAlertWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"An error has occured.", nil) andMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"All text fields should be filled out.", nil)];}];
}

else if (([self.firstNameTextField hasText] || [self.lastNameTextField hasText]) && [self.emailTextField hasText] && [self.passwordTextField hasText]) {

    UserCreateWebService *ucws = [[UserCreateWebService alloc]initWithFirstName:self.firstNameTextField.text andLastName:self.lastNameTextField.text andEmail:self.emailTextField.text andPassword:self.passwordTextField.text];
    NSString *ucwsResponse = [ucws userCreated];
    if ([ucwsResponse isEqualToString:@"Contact already exists"])  {
        [self dismissAlert:^(void){[self presentOkAlertWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"An error has occured.", nil) andMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"A contact with that information already exists. Please enter a different email and try again.", nil)];}];
    }
    else if (ucwsResponse.length > 75 && [[ucwsResponse substringToIndex:75] isEqualToString:@"EX: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."]) {
        [self dismissAlert:^(void){ [self presentOkAlertWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"An error has occured.", nil) andMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"The entered email is not in the required format. Please enter as:\"username@domain.com\"", @"Replace username with the equivalent word and domain with the equivalent word")];}];
    }
    else if ([ucwsResponse isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
        //logs in the newly created user
        User *user = [[[UserLoginService alloc]initWithUsername:self.emailTextField.text andPassword:self.passwordTextField.text] attemptLogin];
        if (!user) {
            [self dismissAlert:^(void){[self presentOkAlertWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Something went wrong.", nil) andMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"Please ensure that you have an internet connection.", nil)];}];
        }
        else {
            //post a notification 
        }
        [self dismissAlert];
        UIAlertView *success = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Registration Complete", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome! Press the Ok button to get started!" , nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]; // Makes Alert View
        [success show]; //shows alert view


    }
    else { //need to beef up the error message with the return from the json.
        [self presentOkAlertWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"An error has occured.", nil) andMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"Your account has not been created. Please check your internet connection or try again later.", nil)];
    }
}
```

presentLoadingAlertWithTitle:

```
 - (void)presentLoadingAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:@"\n" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

CGRect activityIndicatorFrame = alertController.view.bounds;
activityIndicatorFrame.size.height -= 35.0f;
activityIndicatorFrame.origin.y += 35.0f;

UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:activityIndicatorFrame];
[activityIndicator setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[activityIndicator setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];

[alertController.view addSubview:activityIndicator];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:completion];
```

}

```
- (void)presentLoadingAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title
{
[self presentLoadingAlertWithTitle:title completion:nil];
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: "Then it seems to skip over the dispatch_async part, run the rest of the code, and then come back to it." Correct. _That is what async means._ You need to stop and wrap your head around the notion of "asynchronous" before you go any further.

Comment: Further to what Matt said, I suspect that you actually need to look at `[ucws userCreated]`. This is the code that you need to execute asynchronously or at least on a different thread. If this is a network operation and your are executing synchronously it will block the main queue (and therefore your UI) so your alert doesn't get a chance to execute until that method has completed.

Comment: Okay, so I thought the purpose of the dispatch_asynchronous was so that it would execute independently of what everything else was doing on the main thread. Am I wrong here? If I want it to complete 100% of the way through before calling the next thing, do I need to dispatch it synchronously?

Comment: No, dispatch_async will put it in the queue to execute independently but your code is already running on the main queue, so it can't execute until your current block of code is finished. Your current task won't be preempted in order to execute the new task immediately.  As I said your problem is that your network operation isn't being dispatched onto another queue so the main queue is blocked